# Segmentation fault in a maze program in c

Tags: c

This is a maze solving program. It is supposed to run with a txt file that contains the maze, which is in this format:

```
5 5
%%%%%
S % %
% % %
%   E
%%%%%
```

The first 2 numbers are supposed to be the width and height of the maze, '%' is supposed to be the wall, 'S' is start, 'E' is end, mark '*' for the solution path, and mark '~' for tried but failed path.

Here is my code for solveMazeDFS:

```
int solveMazeDFS(maze_t * maze, int col, int row)
{                 //This is line 102
  if(col < 0 || row < 0 || col >= maze->width || row >= maze->height){
    return 0;
  }
  if(maze->cells[row][col] == '%' || maze->cells[row][col] == '~'){
    return 0;
  }
  if(maze->cells[row][col] == 'E'){
    return 1;
  }
  if(maze->cells[row][col] == ' '){
    maze->cells[row][col] = '*';
  }

  if(solveMazeDFS(maze, col - 1, row) == 1){
    return 1;
  }
  if(solveMazeDFS(maze, col + 1, row) == 1){
    return 1;
  }
  if(solveMazeDFS(maze, col, row - 1) == 1){
    return 1;
  }
  if(solveMazeDFS(maze, col, row + 1) == 1){
    return 1;
  }
  maze->cells[row][col] = '~';
  return 0;
}
```

I keep getting segmentation fault for this. I ran the code with valgrind to see where exactly is wrong, it tells me Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0x1ffe801000 at 0x400AED: solveMazeDFS (maze.c:102)
So basically line 102 is the left curly bracket after the int solveMazeDFS(maze_t * maze, int col, int row). I'm new to this, honestly quite  lost at this point.

Comment: You probably have infinite recursion.

Comment: Run the program under a debugger, and you should be able to see how it's recursing and why the recursion isn't ending.

Comment: Think about the cases you're not checking in your early outs.

Comment: You also need to check for `*` at the start to avoid going back and forth

Comment: Using recursion this way is not a good idea. Use iteration instead.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Can't open the file.\n");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdour`  2) since the file failed to open, the code must not continue.  So the next line should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  similar considerations exist for: `printf("The size of the maze cannot be read.\n");`

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `int r, c, w, h;`  variable names (and function parameters) should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  Such variable names as declared in the copied statement are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: OT: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: OT: the function: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Werror -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if(maze->cells[row][col] == ' '){
    maze->cells[row][col] = '*';
  }
```

You need an `else return 0;` here. Otherwise, you can just go back and forth infinitely. If the square is already taken, we can't take it again.